# Display DirectX .x file on web browser or convert to .obj file

Tags: javascript, html, directx

For an app I have, users upload and share .x files. I want to be able to display the .x files in the browser so users can preview each others' files, but can't seem to find any Javascript libraries to do so.

So far, I've found JSC3D, which works to display .obj files. Is there a way to automate conversion of .x files to .obj files on the backend, so I can serve the .obj files with JSC3D? Otherwise, is there currently any way to display .x files on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

[`assimp`](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) can handle the conversion from `x` to `obj`. 
Afterwards any WebGL framework will do since virtually all of them read Obj - JSC3D is an option, so is [the very popular Three.js](http://threejs.org/).